# Mapping XML field's in php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing, schema

I am having a very large xml. It has fields Like

```
<SegrigatedQualification>
    <EducationSplit>
      <University><![CDATA[G. H. Raisoni College of Engineering]]></University>
      <Degree><![CDATA[Engineering]]></Degree>
      <Year><![CDATA[2011]]></Year>
    </EducationSplit>
    <EducationSplit>
      <University><![CDATA[G. H. Raisoni College of Engineering]]></University>
      <Degree><![CDATA[Engineering]]></Degree>
      <Year><![CDATA[2010]]></Year>
    </EducationSplit>
    <EducationSplit>
      <University><![CDATA[G. H. Raisoni College of Engineering]]></University>
      <Degree><![CDATA[Engineering]]></Degree>
      <Year><![CDATA[2009]]></Year>
    </EducationSplit>
    <EducationSplit>
      <University><![CDATA[Diploma  I.T]]></University>
      <Degree><![CDATA[Diploma  I.T]]></Degree>
      <Year><![CDATA[2008]]></Year>
    </EducationSplit>
    <EducationSplit>
      <University><![CDATA[Nasik Board]]></University>
      <Degree><![CDATA[S.S.C]]></Degree>
      <Year><![CDATA[2003]]></Year>
    </EducationSplit>
  </SegrigatedQualification>
```

I want to map the field's and make table then store the information of all xml into the table. Problem is that If i create a column SagrigratedQualificaton how can i store the Education Split or University,Degree,Year in one Row? Cause if i create separate columns the information of university,degree etc will take two or more rows this way the table become redundant. What is the best way to map the xml into table?

Comment: You should read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), then take a shot at creating a table structure from what you've learned.

Comment: i got you want to say but many fields are dynamic so later if that field is not present in table i'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

relational database... each xml structure should be a different record in different table. 
Or just keep it simple and store this in some TEXT or BLOB field.

Comment: Hmm that will be last option for me.

Comment: then improvise... create table structure that works best for you and dump info there. You can merge parent/child node names into more creative field names `educationsplit_university`, etc... then write recursive function to convert your xml to single dimensional key=>value array and save it

Comment: hmm i can try this but 1st step is to create table with fields in xml and then mapping with key value all this is going to take too much time i have to find an easy solution.

Comment: if you write 1 recursive function to generate single dimensional array from xml then simply dump the keys using `array_keys` and create your table.

Comment: yes right exactly. That's what i am searching for is there anything readily available otherwise i have to write own xml parser according to the needs that will take care of table generation and field making and storing data into table. Thanks. :)

Comment: you dont need to reinvent the wheel. Simply load xml with `simplexml_load_string` or `simplexml_load_file`. Cast the simplexml object you get to array and loop through children and repeat casting process... this way you work with assoc array and not xml

Comment: Yes done written one function which maps the xml to array then made 2-3 tables according to the elements in it and then inserted values n particular table by comparing key with table field. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like MagicParser to extract the data and then map it to your own table and fields with ease.

Comment: thanks let me checkout for it.

Comment: You can check it out and see how it's parsing your xml here: http://www.magicparser.com/demo?fileID=50D402D0B7893&record=2

Comment: Thanks i tried this tool. Tool is nice but it didn't parse my all fields. This tool i can use for small xml's.

Comment: It parsed what you put for an example just fine. I can see all the records broken down. Make sure you click on the Prev Record 2 Next to see all your records!

Comment: the xml i given in question is small piece of original xml that is parsed well. But the original xml's many field's are not parsed even many fields are excluded which having "html" data.

Comment: That's not going to matter. I am a fan of MagicParser and have been using it for years over any other function/code. I can throw just about anything at MP and it parses it. Inside the function you just do a foreach() statement and then start mapping your variables to $val. Once you've done that - a simple insert - and be done with it.

Comment: that tool is good but it doesn't give me what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require("MagicParser.php");

function myRecordHandler($record){


// This is where you write your code to process each record, such as loading a database

// The following code will print out each field in your sample data:
print $record["EDUCATIONSPLIT"];
print $record["UNIVERSITY"];
print $record["DEGREE"];
print $record["YEAR"];
}

$data = ""; // string variable contianing the data to parse

MagicParser_parse("string://".$data,"myRecordHandler","xml|SEGRIGATEDQUALIFICATION/EDUCATIONSPLIT/");
?>
```

NOTE: If you want to load it from an actual file then you would simply remove the $data reference and make the MagicParser_parse like this:

```
MagicParser_parse("your-xml-file.xml".$data,"myRecordHandler","xml|SEGRIGATEDQUALIFICATION/EDUCATIONSPLIT/");
```

Comment: Thanks Alex couldnt get it right :(